# The path template on the action is not a valid OData path template

Tags: c#, odata, entity

I have defined POST method in my OData controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ODataRoute("Users/BulkUserUpdate/")]
    public HttpResponseMessage BulkUserUpdate([FromBody] BulkUserUpdateModel bulkModel)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (Guid userId in bulkModel.UserIds)
            {
                ...
            }
            ...
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ...
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }
```

When starting app I get error: The path template 'Users/BulkUserUpdate/' on the action 'BulkUserUpdate' in controller 'Users' is not a valid OData path template. Bad Request - Error in query syntax.

My config in EntityDataModel:

```
var userType = builder.EntitySet<UserModel>("Users").EntityType;
ActionConfiguration bulkUserUpdate = userType.Action("BulkUserUpdate");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OjamaYellow

Follow [OData Spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata03/os/complete/part1-protocol/odata-v4.0-errata03-os-part1-protocol-complete.html#_Toc453752311), it says:

*To invoke an action bound to a resource, the client issues a POST request to an action URL. An action URL may be obtained from a previously returned entity representation or constructed by appending the **namespace- or alias-qualified** action name to a URL that identifies a resource whose type is the same as, or derives from, the type of the binding parameter of the action.*

So, your `[ODataRoute("Users/BulkUserUpdate/")]` has two problems:

1. you should use namespace qualified action name to call action. for example: `~.. /YourNameSapce.BulkUserUpdate`
2. your action is bound to non-collection type, so you should call the action on the non-collection.

So, the correct attribute routing string should be:

```
[ODataRoute(Users({myKey})/YourNamespace.BulkUserUpdate")]
```

And your method in the controller should have an argument to accept the "myKey".

```
public HttpResponseMessage BulkUserUpdate([FromODataUri]string myKey, [FromBody] BulkUserUpdateModel bulkModel)
```

=========================Update 10/20/2017===============

Response from OjamaYellow:

*but what if I dont want to have key in my url. So I actually want to have unbound action*

For the unbound action, you can directly call "Action" method from "builder", for example:

`ActionConfiguration actionConfig = builder.Action("xxx");`

unbound action is called through action import,  Follow [OData Spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata03/os/complete/part1-protocol/odata-v4.0-errata03-os-part1-protocol-complete.html#_Toc453752311) says:

*to invoke an action through an action import, the client issues a POST request to a URL identifying the action import. The canonical URL for an action import is the service root, followed by **the name of the action import**.*

so, the correct attribute routing string for unbound action should be:

`[ODataRoute("yourActionImportName")]`

=============update 10/24/2017=========

if you want to use `Users/BulkUserUpdate`, that's the action bounded to the collection of entity.

So, at model builder, you should call:

```
var userType = builder.EntitySet<UserModel>("Users").EntityType;
ActionConfiguration bulkUserUpdate = userType.Collection.Action("BulkUserUpdate");
```

please be noted "Collection" call after `userType`.

Also, please change the [ODataRoute("...")] in your controller.
Hope it can help.

Comment: but what if I dont want to have key in my url. So I actually want to have unbound action

Comment: this way it work but only if route is BulkUserUpdate but not if I have Users/BulkUserUpdate which I want to have

Comment: thanks, I dont get an error anymore. I do still have issues with parameter bulkModel, for which I alwasy get null when making request with json format. I added bulkUserUpdate.CollectionParameter<BulkUserUpdateModel>("bulkModel"). Should it be written differently?

Comment: Please make sure you should call "CollectionParammeter or CollectionEntityParameter". 
For the action/function parameter, please refer to the tutorial: http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#04-07-action-parameter-support, there are more detail about each type of parameter.